# Define Anchor functions only for tests

Tags: anchor, anchor-test

I'm writing an Anchor program and would like to include a couple functions that modify certain values during tests in a way that would be tedious to do with the real program interface. I don't want to keep this for my production code. What is the standard way of doing this in Anchor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use conditional compiling like this:

```
#[cfg(feature = "is-test")]
pub fn increase_counter_function(mut count: u64) -> u64 {
    count += 1;
    count
}
```

and then you set the value in the cargo.toml

```
[features]
is-test = []
```